# Add label to geom_vline within a ggplot2 figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

so far I can manage to build the following geom_density figure using ggpot2:

```
cuts1 <- data.frame(Ref="p", vals=c(140))
cuts2 <- data.frame(Ref="s", vals=c(300))
cuts3 <- data.frame(Ref="m", vals=c(250))
cuts <- rbind(cuts1, cuts2, cuts3)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp)) +
     geom_density(color = "black",
               fill = 4,
               alpha = 1) +
   geom_vline(data = cuts , aes(xintercept=vals, color= Ref) )
```

[image]

And I wondered if someone knew a way to plot the geom_vline much more like that :

[image]

Where the **lines do not reach the top and bottom of the figure** and where the labels are all **displayed with a rotation**.

Comment: Use `geom_segment` and `geom_text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)

cuts1 <- data.frame(Ref="p", vals=c(140))
cuts2 <- data.frame(Ref="s", vals=c(300))
cuts3 <- data.frame(Ref="m", vals=c(250))
cuts <- rbind(cuts1, cuts2, cuts3)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp)) +
  geom_density(color = "black",
               fill = 4,
               alpha = 1) +
  geom_segment(data = cuts, aes(x=vals, xend = vals,
                                y = 0, yend = max(density(mtcars$disp)[[2]]),
                                color= Ref), key_glyph = "vpath") +
  geom_text(data = cuts, aes(x = vals, y = max(density(mtcars$disp)[[2]]) * 1.02,
                             label = Ref), nudge_x = 5, angle = 45)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [geom_segment](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.1/topics/geom_segment), you can set the `yend` parameter to where you want your lines to end.